# TRANWRD to fix Merge error?

Tags: sas

I recently combined two datasets with a pretty straightforward `Merge` statement. I was using an ACS dataset and a Census population dataset. I needed a flag from the latter to be in the former. When I merged, the place variable (town/county, state) was not de-duplicated because one dataset used state abbreviations while the other used the full spelling:

```
   Obs GeoID           GeoName
    1  .            Abbeville County, SC    
    2  45001        Abbeville County, South Carolina
```

I need to change the GeoName for `Obs1` so that it equals `Obs2`

Would an `index` function work? Or do I need the `TRANWRD` function? Thanks.

Solved:

```
data _null_;
length geoName $100;
GeoName_C = scan(GeoName,1,',');
GeoName_S = scan(GeoName,-1,',');  *-1 scans from the right in case you could have commas in the city - check for this and adjust GeoName_C to include them if it is possible;
GeoName_S_F = stnamel(strip(GeoName_S));
GeoName = catx(',',GeoName_C,GeoName_S_F);
put _all_;
run;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I would do is separate the city from the state and use SAS's inbuilt function `stnamel` to convert the abbreviation to the full name.

```
data _null_;
length geoName $100;
GeoName='Abbeville Road, SC';
GeoName_C = scan(GeoName,1,',');
GeoName_S = scan(GeoName,-1,',');  *-1 scans from the right in case you could have commas in the city - check for this and adjust GeoName_C to include them if it is possible;
GeoName_S_F = stnamel(strip(GeoName_S));
GeoName = catx(',',GeoName_C,GeoName_S_F);
put _all_;
run;
```

Comment: That successfully split the town and the state abbreviation. However, the GeoName_S_F is showing as blanks, and the GeoName is not concatenating.

Comment: What version of SAS do you have?

Comment: 9.3. The GeoName_S is also not populating.

Comment: Apparently, stnamel isn't smart enough to strip off spaces. Disappointing.  Fixing the answer to reflect use of `strip`.

Comment: The above example works in 9.4 (and should in 9.3).  If GeoName_S isn't populating, you have some other issue I would guess - update with what happens when you use the above.  Doublecheck lengths, perhaps that's one possible issue.

Comment: Awesome. That seems to work, except I didn't include the first GeoName statement in your code. Final code that corrects for everything is added to the question. Thanks so much!